# Fancy new 64GB USB 3.0 thumb drive writes at only 10mb/s

Tags: usb, usb-3

As you can see, read is as advertised and expected from USB 3.0, but write is terrible.

[image]

It's formatted with ext4, plugged into USB 3.0 port on a desktop computer 3 years old. 
I tried with 200mb sample files, and results were the same.

When I went to copy real files (several GBs) it actually got to 27mb/s, but still that's rather low. What am I doing wrong?

This is the drive in question, it's the latest model, 2015:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/111617728061?_trksid=p2057872.m2748.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: Write speed is always slower than read speed. I'm pretty sure this is an advertising trick, where they only tell you the faster speed.

Comment: Is it being detected as a USB 3.0 device?  The speeds you are getting are USB 2.0 speds.  Also update all of your units to the same you have some conversion errors in your question.  The screenshot is clear, it clearly indicates 10.9 MB/sec  What is the adverised Write and Read speeds for this device.

Comment: Reviews on Amazon suggest a maximum write speed of around 30-45 MB/s. If write speed is important, you could check reviews on places like [The Wirecutter](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/the-best-usb-3-0-thumb-drive/). P.S. your question title and some of your text refers to read speeds when the chart clearly shows read speeds in excess of 120 MB/s.

Comment: @Zacharee1 yes I'm aware, the thing is 10mb/s write speed is way too low

Ramhound, not true. The read spead is obviously a 3.0 one
No idea about what conversion errors you are talking about, seems consistent to me

AndrewMorton, yes ive said read in the title by mistake. I'm only concerned with the write speed